# How to generate pdftotext same as pdf generated by xpdf in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdftotext, xpdf

> I am using [spatie library](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text) of Laravel to convert pdf into text. I am
> using Xpdf. This is my code for conversion of pdftotext.

```
$text1 = (new Pdf('C:\xpdf-tools-win-4.00\bin64\pdftotext.exe'))
->setPdf($dynamipathoffileuploadedbyuser)
->setOptions(['layout','layout'])
->text();
$string = $text1;
echo $string;
```

As you see above code user will upload some pdf file and then I am converting this file in `text()`.  I am using `->setOptions(['layout','layout'])` to display my text format as same as PDF file.

> Criteria 1:
>
> If I used word file as pdf then `setOptions` works great. It shows me
> same print what it is in pdf.
>
> Criteria 2:
>
> If I used my Laravel blade file with HTML code inside that.
> `setOptions` didn't work in this case. I don't know how to tackle this
> issue.

Is there any other option to set `text()` same like pdf. I need this because after conversion of pdftotext I have to gather the same information from this and store in the database.